# Trying to store an object on an array on a server using spring boot

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, spring, spring-boot

Im working on a school project to store an object in an array on a server with spring boot, but its not working and i can figure out what is wrong with the code. The site is suppose to reprisent a site to buy movie tickets and store/show the info on the html document. and you can delete every stored object in the array with one click. When i try to store the object nothing happens and nothing is being sent with spring.

```js
$(() => {
    $("#kjop").click (() => {
        const film = $("#film");
        const antall = $("#antall")
        const fornavn = $("#forNavn");
        const etternavn = $("#etterNavn");
        const telefon = $("#telefornr");
        const epost = $("#epost");

        const billett = {
            film: film.val(),
            antall: antall.val(),
            fornavn: fornavn.val(),
            etternavn: etternavn.val(),
            telefon: telefon.val(),
            epost: epost.val(),
        };

        if (validering(billett)) {
            $.post("/billett", billett, () => hent());


            film.val("");
            antall.val("");
            fornavn.val("");
            etternavn.val("");
            telefon.val("");
            epost.val("");
        } else {
            console.log("Mangler input");
        }
    });

        $("#slettBilett").click(() => {
            $.ajax("/billett", {
                type: "DELETE",
                success: () => hent(),
                error: (jqXhr, textStatus, errorMessage) => console.log(errorMessage)
            });
        });
    });

const hent = () => $.get("/billett", billett => utskrift (billett));

const validering = billett => {
    if (billett.film === "") return false
    else if (billett.antall ==="") return false
    else if (billett.fornavn === "") return false
    else if (Billett.etternavn === "") return false
    else if (billett.telefon === "") return false
    else return billett.epost !== "";
}



const utskrift = billett => {
    let ut = "<table><tr>" +
        "<th>Film</th><th>antall</th><th>Navn</th><th>Etternavn</th><th>Telefonnr</th><th>Epost</th>" +
        "</tr>";
    for (let b of billett) {
        ut += "<tr>";
        ut += "<td>" + b.film + "</td><td>" + b.antall + "</td><td>" + b.navn + "</td><td>" + b.etternavn + "</td><td>" + b.tlf + "</td><td>" + b.epost + "</td>";
        ut += "</tr>";
    }
    ut += "</table>";
    $("#bestilt").html(ut);
}
```

```css
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.billett;
import com.example.demo.AppRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/lagringserver/")
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    AppRepository repo;

    @PostMapping("/billett")
    public void lagre(billett billett) {
                repo.leggInn(billett);
            }

    @GetMapping("/billett")
    public ArrayList<billett> hent() {

        return repo.hentAlle();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/billett")
    public void slett() {
        repo.slettBilett();
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Oblig 1</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<h1>Bestilling av kinobiletter</h1>

<div>
    Velg film:
    <select id="film">
        <option value="non">Velg film her</option>
        <option>Iron man</option>
        <option>Troya</option>
        <option>Avengers</option>
        <option>The green mile</option>
        <option>God father</option>
        <option>Fight club</option>
    </select><span id="valgterr" style = "color:#ff0000"></span>
</div>

<br /><br />

<div>
    Antall <input type="text" id="antall" /><span id="antallerr" style = "color:red"> </span>
</div>

<br /><br />

<table>

    <tr>
        <td>Fornavn</td><td> <input type="text" id="forNavn" /> </td><td><span id="forNavnerr" style = "color:red"> </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Etternavn</td><td> <input type="text" id="etterNavn"/> </td><td><span id="etterNavnerr" style = "color:red"> </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Telefonnr</td><td> <input type="text" id="telefornr"/> </td><td><span id="tlferr" style = "color:red"> </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Epost</td><td> <input type="text" id="epost"/> </td><td><span id="eposterr" style = "color:red"> </span></td>
    </tr>


</table>

<button id="kjop();">Kjøp Billet</button>

<br /><br />

<h2>
    Alle Billetter
</h2>
<div id="bestilt">
</div>
<br /><br />
<button id="slettBilett();">Slett alle billetter</button>

</body>
</html>
```

```js
package com.example.demo;

public class billett {
    private String film;
    private String antall;
    private String fornavn;
    private String etternavn;
    private String telefon;
    private String epost;

        public billett (String film, String antall, String fornavn, String etternavn, String telefon, String epost) {
            this.film = film;
            this.antall= antall;
            this.fornavn = fornavn;
            this.etternavn = etternavn;
            this.telefon = telefon;
            this.epost = epost;
        }

        public String getFilm() {

            return film;
        }

        public void setFilm(String film){

            this.film = film;
        }
        public String getAntall(){

            return antall;
        }

        public void setAntall(String fornavn){

            this.antall = antall;
        }

        public String getFornavn(){

            return fornavn;
        }

        public void setFornavn(String fornavn){

            this.fornavn = fornavn;
        }
        public String getEtternavn(){

            return etternavn;
        }

        public void setEtternavn (String etternavn){
            this.etternavn = etternavn;
        }
        public String getTelefon(){
            return telefon;
        }

        public void setTelefon (String telefon){
            this.telefon = telefon;
        }
        public String getEpost(){
            return epost;
        }

        public void setEpost (String epost){
            this.epost = epost;
        }

    }
```

```css
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.billett;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Repository
public class AppRepository {
    private final ArrayList<billett> billettliste = new ArrayList<>();

    public void leggInn(billett billett) {
        billettliste.add(billett);
    }

    public ArrayList<billett> hentAlle () {
        return billettliste;
    }

    public void slettBilett() {
        billettliste.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: "When i try to store the object nothing happens and nothing is being sent with spring". How do you know this? Did you see the browser console to see if the request is being sent to the server? Have you enable Spring debug to see if it's receiving the requests? Is the server responding with an error or is not responding at all?

Comment: console are not showing any errors and network dont show anything being sent over

Comment: i have an heroku link where i have uploaded everything to with github https://skoleoblig2.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using arraylist to store the data, however, keep in mind this data will disappear once you restart the application. I assume you want to use a database. Spring provides you with a straightforward solution (spring-data-jpa) that abstracts you from the boiler plate code and lets you change databases without any problems.
First of all choose the database you want to store your data in.
https://dzone.com/articles/using-mysql-jdbc-driver-with-spring-boot

Then you can create a repository

```
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.billett;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.ArrayList;

@Repository
public interface AppRepository extends CrudRepository<Billett, Long>{
}
```

Under the hood, on runtime, spring boot will generate the proxy class which will have basic CRUD (Create Update Delete) methods, which you can call and presist your data.

Comment: i will look into this, but we haven't learned about this yet :P but will that fix my problem to begin with? cause it wont take my inputs and store it at all. when i have my code in intellij  import com.example.demo.billett; are greyed out and im thinking it cant find the controller and apprepository at all

Comment: Spotted a mistake in your controller
So in public void lagre(billett billett) you need to change it to
public void lagre(@RequestBody Billett billett), which will indicate that you are expecting a json object that will be mapped to your POJO (plain java object). Also in your repository I would suggest you to have a hashmap instead of an array list, since you can simulate DB query by ID and you will not have to traverse the whole list just to get a single value :) Hope it helps, if not drop me a private message and we will fix it:) As of front end code, cant really help you, sorry

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your HTML. This line is wrong:

```
<button id="kjop();">Kjøp Billet</button>
```

It should be:

```
<button id="kjop">Kjøp Billet</button>
```

The problem is that you are not attaching the "click" event listener to the button because of the wrong ID. So this is doing nothing:

```
$("#kjop").click (() => {
    ...
});
```